# Entity Framework User Roles Many to Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

Hi I'm trying to set up my entity framework for a many to many relationship between User and Role.

The picture below shows what's in the database:

[image: Many to Many relationships]

The Model for User is:

```
public class User : IEntity
    {
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        //Navigation properties
        //public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

Model for Role is:

```
public class Role : IEntity
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        //Navigation Properties
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

UserRole is:

```
public class UserRole
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        //Navigation properties
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

So I thought I had this set up fine but in my code I go something like:

```
var roles = from r in user.Roles
                        select r.Name;
```

and it shoots itself giving errors of:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid object name 'dbo.RoleUser'.
```

so I added the following to the context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(i => i.Roles)
                .WithMany(u => u.Users);

}
```

However now I'm getting errors of:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid column name 'Role_RoleId'.
Invalid column name 'User_UserId'.

So surely I don't have something set up here correctly. Can andybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to model the link table `UserRole` as a class since it has only the primary keys of the tables participate in the relationship. So remove the `UserRole` class.

If you are modeling an existing database, EF may infer the link table name to be `RoleUser`. To avoid this you can configure the link table as follows.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(i => i.Roles)
            .WithMany(u => u.Users)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserRole");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });

 }
```

Comment: How about the case that the Role entity does not know the User entity? How to write the configuration code?